# Cannot read property 'class' of undefined

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using the `fullCalendar` plugin with `fullCalendar extension: https://github.com/mherrmann/fullcalendar-columns`

now in the setup the authour suggest to import in the script `fullcalendar.js` but I need to use `fullcalendar.min.js`. If I include `fullcalendar.js` the error above isn't displayed but all the `easyappointments` library is structured on the min version so I can't use the `fullcalendar.js`.. Anyway, if I import the `fullcalendar.min.js` I get this error:

> var AgendaView = fc.views.agenda.class || fc.views.agenda;

in the class `fullcalendar-columns.js`

this is the jFiddle of the author: http://jsfiddle.net/jkmda709/2/
how you can see all working fine with the `fullcalendar.js` but if I import `fullcalendar.min.js` seems that custom class `fullcalendar-columns.js` is broken.

How I can solve this problem? There's something must to change?

Comment: It seems that the non-minified version contains an error, I suggest you just use the minified version instead and create an Issue in the github repository.

Comment: I've already create the issue, could you help me out?